# jqueryブラウザ画面サイズ取得について

Tags: jquery

ブラウザの画面サイズの取得についてwindow.innerWidthとwindow.innerHeightを使用しています。
しかしcssを使用してzoom倍率を変更している場合それを考慮した値を返してくれません。

例えばブラウザの画面サイズが横1000pxだったとします。
拡大率が100%の場合は問題ないのですが、例えば90%に変更していた場合は表示できる値は変わってくると思います(大体1111pxくらい？)
下記のように拡大率を変更し
 $("html").css("zoom", "90%");
window.innerWidthで取得すると常に1000pxしか返してくれません。
拡大率を考慮して取得する方法はあるのでしょうか？

ちなみに使用しているブラウザはchromeです。
Google Chrome 55.0.2883.87 (Official Build) m （64 ビット）

詳しい方ご教授をお願い致します。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`document.body.clientWidth`で取得できないでしょうか？

ちなみに

`document.body.clientWidth / window.innerWidth`で拡大率が取得できます。

Comment: おおお取れました！ありがとうございます、助かりました！

Comment: @user20198 動作したようで何よりです。もし解決したようでしたら承認をお願いいたします。